# Running Json file in VScode using Python

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I am very fresh in Python. I would like to read JSON files in Python, but I did not get what are the problems. Please see the image.

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code directly rather than putting in an image.

Comment: ```with open(r'path/to/read/','r') as file:
data = json.load(file)``` add 'r' in that..

Comment: It reverts back the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a mode to the open() function. In this case I think you're trying to read the file, so your mode would be "r". Your code should be:

```
with open(r'path/to/read/','r') as file: 
   data = json.load(file)
```

Your code should run now.

Answer (score 0):

Your path should not contain spaces. Please modify the file path.

Generally speaking, the file path is best to be in full English with no spaces and no special characters.

[image]

Comment: I modified the file path to f = open('C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\transactions.json', encoding='utf-8')

but, It didnot work : f = open('C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\transactions.json', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Use `/`, using \ requires translation, that is \\.

Comment: I wrote:
import sys
import os
import JSON

with open(r"C:/Users/Alireza/Desktop/transactions.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file, encodings='utf-8')

Comment: It showed me:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python2\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    data = json.load(file, encodings='utf-8')
  File "C:\Users\Alireza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Alireza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
TypeError: JSONDecoder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encodings'

Comment: **unexpected keyword argument 'encodings'**. Delete it.

Comment: I wrote: import sys
import os
import json

with open(r"C:/Users/Alireza/Desktop/transactions.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

But the same problems still existed. I deleted 'encodings'. I don't know why my json file can not open

Comment: show me your screen.

Comment: My screenshot : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TL_R7IeCnKbIu__hVqY4ZkYau4r1yJsy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want to see what is written in the terminal as well as run in pycharm?

Comment: Is your json file correct? Is there content in the file? Is the format in the json correct?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import sys
import os
import json

def JsonRead(str):
    with open(str, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

new_Data = JsonRead(filePath)
```

Then import JsonRead in project

Comment: it did not work.
     f = open('C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\transactions.json', encoding='utf-8')
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: You should use ;      f= with open(path,encoding='utf-8')